# OnClick event in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, button, onclick

Here is my code, for my MP3 streaming player (mp3player.swf) in AS3

```
var stream:String               = root.loaderInfo.parameters.stream;
var sndObject:Sound             = new Sound();
var chaObject:SoundChannel      = new SoundChannel() ;

btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopPlayback);   
btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startPlayback);

btnStop.visible = false;

function startPlayback(e:MouseEvent):void {
    btnPlay.visible = false;
    btnStop.visible = true;
    //stream  = root.loaderInfo.parameters.stream;
    sndObject = new Sound(new URLRequest(stream));
    chaObject = sndObject.play(0);  
}

function stopPlayback(e:MouseEvent):void {
    chaObject.stop();       
    btnPlay.visible = true;
    btnStop.visible = false;
}
```

And here is my html file, that contains mp3player.swf

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
    <head>
        MP3 Player
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="areas">
                <h3>MP3 Player</h3>
                <div id="player">
                    <object id="f4Player" width="300" height="181" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mp3player.swf"> 
                    <param name="movie" value="mp3player.swf" /> 
                    <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
                    <param name="menu" value="false" /> 
                    <param name="scale" value="noscale" /> 
                    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
                    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
                    <param name="swlivevonnect" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="cachebusting" value="false">
                    <param name="flashvars" value="stream=http://123.30.174.216:8768/VOVGT"/> 
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"> 
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/> 
                    </a> 
                    <a href="http://gokercebeci.com/dev/flvplayer" title="flv player">flv player</a> 
                    </object> 
                </div>                
            </div>
            <!-- /development area -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Problem is when I click the play button, it plays a sound, then I click stop, and click play again, however this time it doesn't play any sound.Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `init sound object outside startPlayback` function
otherwise, it will create new sound instance each time you click play

put

`sndObject = new Sound(new URLRequest(stream));`

before this line

`function startPlayback(e:MouseEvent):void {`

Comment: thanks you, but if i do this, this music "can't stop" streaming. eg, i play radio streaming (live streaming), when i do this, stop function "not stop", it same the pause function. It mean when i click stop and play, it play from when i click stop. but i want it play new progress from live streaming. can you help me?